ServiceBusRetryOptions not working with SessionProcessor
I have created a service which starts and creates a connection to given Azure Service Bus Topic.
I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus Sdk with .NET 7 and I am trying to implement retry policy but it seems like the MaxDelivery is the only thing that is contributing to retries of processing a message.
Here, I have thrown an exception to see the count of retries which I expected to be 2 but turns out to be 10 (i.e DeliveryCount = 10). This seems to be the same as what I set in MaxDeliveryCount (10) in Azure Portal.
Here is the code:
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace ServiceBusProcessor;
public class ServiceBusProcessorHandler : BackgroundService
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = "";
    private static readonly string TopicName = "";
    private static readonly string SubscriptionName = "";
    private readonly ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient;
    private readonly ServiceBusSessionProcessor serviceBusSessionProcessor;
    public ServiceBusProcessorHandler()
    {
        this.serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(ConnectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions()
        {
            RetryOptions = new ServiceBusRetryOptions()
            {
                Mode = ServiceBusRetryMode.Exponential,
                MaxRetries = 2,
                MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000),
                Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)
            }
        });
        this.serviceBusSessionProcessor = this.serviceBusClient.CreateSessionProcessor(TopicName, SubscriptionName, new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions()
        {
            MaxConcurrentSessions = 100,
            PrefetchCount = 100,
            SessionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        });
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        this.serviceBusSessionProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += (args) =>
    {
            Console.WriteLine($"DeliveryCount: {args.Message.DeliveryCount}");
            Console.WriteLine(args.Message.Body);
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not Implemented");
        };

        this.serviceBusSessionProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += (args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Exception);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        await this.serviceBusSessionProcessor.StartProcessingAsync();
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is stopping.");
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

My use case is simple, try to retry without Scheduling the message (or republishing to the service bus) in case there is an internal server error.

I got the retry count 2 and then got an exception with the console code as shown in this image. Is this what you are trying to get?

@DasariKamali this is exactly what I am trying to do. How did you achieve this without a retry framework like polly?

The retry options configure implicit retries for service operations.  They do not play a role for the code in your handlers.   If you want explicit retries in your application code, you'll need to implement them as part of your handler.  The answer by Deasari Kamali below is a good example of doing so.

I tried the following code to set the maximum retry count to 2, with an exception, when sending a message to the Azure ServiceBus Topic.
Code :
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Polly;
using Polly.Retry;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ServiceBusProcessor = Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor;

namespace MyServiceBusProcessorApp 
{
    public class ServiceBusProcessorHandler : BackgroundService
    {
        private static readonly string ConnectionString = "<ServiceBusTopic_connec_string>";
        private static readonly string TopicName = "<Topic_name>";
        private static readonly string SubscriptionName = "<TopicSubscription_name";
        private readonly ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient;
        private readonly ServiceBusProcessor serviceBusProcessor; 
        private readonly AsyncRetryPolicy retryPolicy;

        public ServiceBusProcessorHandler()
        {
            this.serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(ConnectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions()
            {
                RetryOptions = new ServiceBusRetryOptions()
                {
                    Mode = ServiceBusRetryMode.Exponential,
                    MaxRetries = 2,
                    MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000),
                    Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)
                }
            });
            this.serviceBusProcessor = this.serviceBusClient.CreateProcessor(TopicName, SubscriptionName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions()
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 100,
                PrefetchCount = 100,
            });
            this.retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
                                     .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                                        (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine($"Retry {retryCount} encountered an error: {exception.Message}. Waiting {timeSpan} before next retry.");
                                        });
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            this.serviceBusProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += async (args) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await this.retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"DeliveryCount: {args.Message.DeliveryCount}");
                        Console.WriteLine(args.Message.Body);
                        throw new NotImplementedException("Not Implemented");
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed after retries: {ex.Message}");
                }
            };
            this.serviceBusProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += (args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Exception);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            await this.serviceBusProcessor.StartProcessingAsync();
        }
        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service is stopping.");
            await this.serviceBusProcessor.StopProcessingAsync();
            await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<ServiceBusProcessorHandler>();
                });
    }
}

Output :
I sent a message to the Azure ServiceBus Topic as shown below:

I received the following message in the console.

